# Regulating load to find MPP

Tags: battery-charging, mppt

I'm trying to design an MPPT system for photovoltaic cells for a school project.

As far as I understand I have to change the duty cycle of a buck converter to change the voltage of the PV so I can find the largest V*I. And I have to have a variable load.

The part that confuses me is how can I use a battery as the variable load, since it is charged with constant current and I have arbitrary voltage and current on the output of the buck converter.

Should I connect the battery directly to the buck converter, restrict the maximum current based on the battery and charge the battery with changing current?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH6ig9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Instead of maximizing V*I coming out of the panel, maximize the charge current. If the maximized charge current is too high (greater than the maximum allowable charge current), then reduce duty cycle until battery charge current is within the limit (in this case you won't be operating at MPPT anymore, but that is OK).

Comment: Also, as far as your confusion goes, the battery is a variable load because as you increase the current, the voltage remains relatively unchanged. At least in the short term. Which reminds me. You also have to make sure the battery voltage is not too high. If it is, you need to reduce the duty cycle and transition into a constant voltage mode of operation.